# My columns shift to left when trying to read it with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with 6 columns. However, when I try to read it with read_csv, the values associated with column indexes shift to the left by 2 columns. Here is an example of the dataset I am using;

```
 time alpha abeta e2e rg rg2
0.000000 0.402192 3.661472 0.599572 0.606992 0.636918
1.000000 0.411551 3.697878 0.580192 0.604391 0.624746
2.000000 0.354966 3.408603 0.704422 0.622932 0.653885
3.000000 0.359647 3.473973 0.681276 0.624507 0.656729
4.000000 0.359812 3.614721 0.619767 0.619774 0.647542
```

Dont worry about the titles not matching, I opened the file with notepad.
However, when I try to read the file using the code

```py
d=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Casper/Downloads/data.xvg" ,sep=' ')
d.head()
print(d)
```

I get this output;

```
 Unnamed: 0    Unnamed: 1      time  ...       e2e        rg  rg2
0             0.0      0.402192  3.661472  ...  0.636918       NaN  NaN
1             1.0      0.411551  3.697878  ...  0.624746       NaN  NaN
2             2.0      0.354966  3.408603  ...  0.653885       NaN  NaN
3             3.0      0.359647  3.473973  ...  0.656729       NaN  NaN
4             4.0      0.359812  3.614721  ...  0.647542       NaN  NaN
```

As you can see, the columns are shifted to the left by 2, thus there is now 8 columns, which I know for a fact that it isnt true. It just creates new columns out of the blue.

When I try to explicitly give the column titles, like this

```py
d=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Casper/Downloads/data.xvg" ,sep=' ',names=['t','Alpha','abeta','e2e','rg','rg2'])
d.head()
print(d)
```

I get this

```
                        t     Alpha     abeta       e2e        rg  rg2
NaN NaN               time     alpha     abeta       e2e        rg  rg2
0.0 0.402192      3.661472  0.599572  0.606992  0.636918       NaN  NaN
1.0 0.411551      3.697878  0.580192  0.604391  0.624746       NaN  NaN
2.0 0.354966      3.408603  0.704422  0.622932  0.653885       NaN  NaN
3.0 0.359647      3.473973  0.681276  0.624507  0.656729       NaN  NaN
```

Now there are correct number of columns, but the main problem persists. The columns shift to the left for seemingly no reason, and I saw the exact same code working correctly in front of my eyes. I am a beginner, so I have absolutely no idea what could possibly cause this or how to solve this, considering the fact that it does work on another computer with same modules and everything. Thank you for your attention and have a good day.

I realized that the columns are ot displaying correctly, but I have no time to rectify that, I am sorry.

Comment: Three things, maybe you should try to pass  header=0 explicitly and remove the space before the "time" on the header, also index_col=False, which will prevent the first column to be used as index.

Answer (score 0):

There's a leading space in the title row.

Make your data like this

```
time alpha abeta e2e rg rg2
0.000000 0.402192 3.661472 0.599572 0.606992 0.636918
1.000000 0.411551 3.697878 0.580192 0.604391 0.624746
2.000000 0.354966 3.408603 0.704422 0.622932 0.653885
3.000000 0.359647 3.473973 0.681276 0.624507 0.656729
4.000000 0.359812 3.614721 0.619767 0.619774 0.647542
```

On executing the same python code, this will be the output:

```
   time     alpha     abeta       e2e        rg       rg2
0   0.0  0.402192  3.661472  0.599572  0.606992  0.636918
1   1.0  0.411551  3.697878  0.580192  0.604391  0.624746
2   2.0  0.354966  3.408603  0.704422  0.622932  0.653885
3   3.0  0.359647  3.473973  0.681276  0.624507  0.656729
4   4.0  0.359812  3.614721  0.619767  0.619774  0.647542
```

If you're not allowed to modify the data file, use this

```py
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Casper/Downloads/data.xvg", sep=' ',skiprows=1, names=['time', 'alpha', 'abeta', 'e2e', 'rg', 'rg2'])
```